# Prove that the equality holds for any $x,y,z\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For any $x,y,z\geq 0$ we have
\begin{align}
(x-z)^+  - (y-z)^+ = (x-\max\{y,z\})^+ - (y-\max\{x,z\})^+.
\end{align}
I have checked that the equality is true for any ordering of $x$, $y$ and $z$, but is there a way to prove it in a smart way?

Note the $x^+$ denotes the positive part of a number, i.e., $x^+=x$ for $x\geq 0$, and $x^+=0$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality is obvious when $z\ge\max(x,y)$. Note also that wlog, $y\le x$, so that we can assume from now on:
$$x\ge\max(y,z).$$

The identity becomes then
$$(x-z)-\frac{y-z+|y-z|}2=\left(x-\frac{y+z+|y-z|}2\right)-0,$$
which trivially holds.

Note that the hypothesis on the sign of $x,y,z$ was irrelevant.